# No objects or images found to bake to... again

Tags: baking

I've read though many threads related to this and I've yet to find one that works for me.

I have a single object that I originally baked some AO to.  Days later I want to go back and rebake it.  The only problem is, no matter what I do, it won't work and gives me the error every time.

I've made sure the object is selected and the render (camera) icon is ON.  I'm using the standard Blender Render method.

I've attached my scene and left it right to the point to where you should be able to click "Bake".  Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong??  I really don't want any "hack" related answer and am desperate to know the exact issue.

[Attached Object](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aly2tBjDTFD-hoRW-7C3EAWddaoAjQ)

Thanks,
-jeff

Answer (score 1):

Baking started to work when I set Duplication to None (in Properties -> Object tab).

Comment: Thank you so much.  Is this setting the default?  I guess I need to research what that all relates to and how/why it was set that way!